# BVP $\displaystyle \nabla ^2 f + 1 = 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} + f = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: IMG]

How do I approach the above question. I would welcome any suggestions for how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking for radial solutions of the form $f(x,y) = g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$. Observe $$f_x(x,y) = g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$ and $$f_y(x,y) = g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$$ Moreover,
$$
f_{xx}(x,y) = g''(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} + g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}$$
and
$$
f_{yy}(x,y) = g''(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{y^2}{x^2 + y^2} + g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}.$$
Thus
$$
\nabla^2 f(x,y) = f_{xx}(x,y) + f_{yy}(x,y) = g''(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) + \frac{ g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$$
Write $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Solving the stated PDE in $R$ amounts to solving the ODE
$$g''(r) + \frac{g'(r)}{r} + 1 = 0, \quad a < r < b.$$

A general solution to this is $g(r) = -\dfrac{r^2}{4} + \alpha \ln r + C$.

At any point $(x,y)$ along the outer boundary $r = b$ the exterior unit normal vector is 
$$
 n(x,y) = \frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$
so that 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(x,y) = \nabla f \cdot n (x,y) = g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}).$$
Likewise, at any point $(x,y)$ along the inner boundary $r=a$ you have
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(x,y) = -g'(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}).
$$
The boundary values for the PDE become the initial values $g'(b) = -g(b)$ and $g'(a) = g(a)$. You can use these to determine $\alpha$ and $C$ above.